# List view threshold on library

Tags: 2013, list-view, library

Does list view threshold only applies to List or Library also? According to my understanding it applies to library also but the articles I keep reading only mention lists.

If I index some columns in a list, then this list view threshold still applies or not?

Comment: Libraries are a specific type of list so yes the thresholds apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'bypass' the List View Threshold, which also applies to libraries, you need to create indexed columns and use them to filter your documents in the views, but also you need to make sure that **the returned items are less than the LVT**.

That means, that if you index the column 'Created' and create a view that filters on Create <= [Today]-90, if this view returns 6000 items the view will not be displayed (assuming your LVT is 5000 items).

Moreover, if you create a view with multiple filters, make sure that the first filter is the indexed column. If you put as the first filter the non-indexed column the LVT will break it.

So for example, if your view filters on 'Modified <= [Today]-90' and 'Created <= [Today]-90', it will not work if the first column is not indexed, even if the second column is.

Answer (score 0):

In MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx), they're talking about the impact of indexing columns and the fact that it speeds up the query. But they never mentioned the fact that it bypasses the list view threshold.

Another blog mentioned that it effectively bypasses the list view threshold (http://www.abelsolutions.com/2013-blog/working-with-list-view-thresholds-in-sharepoint/), but I trust Microsoft when they're not mentioning something :).

UPDATE : Office blog this time : "To help improve the performance of a large list or library, you can index up to 20 columns. In general, an index on a column enables you to quickly find the rows you want based on the values in that column, even when working with millions of items. When you combine indexes with filtered views, you can quickly retrieve the items you want." (https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#__toc257876239)

Comment: This link will help you better understand the list view threshold (videos) : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-lists-V-Techniques-for-managing-large-lists-13456600-ff66-46ec-a2d2-91736d4a166e